# NSLog not called within block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks

my     `replaceObjectatIndex:withObject:` is not being called when I put it inside a block. I know this because when I `NSLog` in the outer block the value doesn't change. why is the method inside the inner block not being called while the method in the outer block does? what's the difference? 
this is the code:

```
if (cell.selected) {
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] queryDiskCacheForKey:imageID
                                                     done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
     {
         // image is not nil if image was found
         if (image == nil) {
             //image is not found
             [SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]
                                                                 options:0
                                                                progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
              {
                  // progression tracking code
              }
                                                               completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
              {
                  if (image && finished)
                  {
                      // image is finished being downloaded
                      // resize image
                      UIImage *resizedImage = [self imageWithImage:image forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                      // store resized image in cache
                      [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:resizedImage forKey:imageID];
                      //set image view to resized image
                      [textCell.testImage setImage:resizedImage];
                      [self.heightArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row
                                                  withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:image.size.height]];
                  }
                  //delete original sized image
                  image = nil;
              }];
         } else {
             //image is found
             [textCell.testImage setImage:image];
             NSLog(@"image found %@", [self.heightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
         }
     }];
} else {
    //cell is not selected
    textCell.testImage.image = nil;
}
```

By the way, the setImage: method works perfectly but not replaceObjectatIndex:withObject:

Comment: Please explain a little more detailed at what point in time and what is not beeing called.

Comment: well if the method is being called, I thought the NSLog wouldn't print '0' , which is the case if I call my method inside the inner block. but if I call the method in the outer block, the NSLog print '165' when it is called.

Comment: Where do you do that `NSLog()`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are doing but I found an issue in your code: you are using the image even after you set it to `nil`.

**Correction:**

```
//delete original sized image - 
//??image = nil;
[self.heightArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row
                                              withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:image.size.height]];
image = nil;
```

Comment: I've changed my code to your suggestion but it still doesn't work

Comment: Use resizedImage instance instead of image and put NSLog right after replacing object.

Comment: I also did that but it still doesn't work. by the way, 'image' is still not assigned to nil when replaceObjectatIndex: is being called.

Comment: Where you are inserting data in heightArray? Can you show the result of NSLog(@"heightArray : %@, row : %d", heightArray, indexPath.row); for before and after replacingObject?

Comment: the replaceObjectatIndex:withObject: works perfectly when it is not called in this block. if i call it in the outer block the nslog print what i want. not only replaceObjectatIndex:withObject: that cant be called even nslog couldnt work when it is inside the inner block.